# Introduce yourself!

Tags: discussion

Just thanking you all for assisting with my questions, and thought to say hi and introduce myself! What do you think? Is this a good idea?

I'm Pearl. I'm a teacher in Toronto, Canada. I've been assigned to teach law and thanks to all of you, am trying to learn it myself. I got no law degree, but got a B.A. and B.Ed. from York University.

Answer (score 3):

People typically don't share personal details on the Q&A portion of the site. But you might consider chatting with others on our affiliated chat site⁨—the [Sidebar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar). It's pretty sleepy over there, and most users confine their discussions to digging deeper into the questions, but I have seen some personal discussion, too.

Comment: I'd add that if you want to share personal information and background [your profile](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3391/koffman?tab=profile) is the best place to do so.  Meanwhile: Welcome to Law.SE, and I hope you'll continue with your contributions!